# Using rsync command with email address

Tags: linux, rsync

I am trying to use rsync on my mac. When I normally type out a command I am only using user for a username.  However, this time my USERNAME is mail@user.com. How do I use an email address as a username in an rsync command?

The command I am trying to do is

```
rsync -rva /directory/that/is/local user@mail.com@host.domain.com:/another/remote/directory
```

The other option I could work with is a rsync client for OSX. But I can't see that as being the long term solution when linux uses rsync for a lot!

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
rsync -rva -e 'ssh -l user@mail.com' /directory/that/is/local host.domain.com:/another/remote/directory
```